# CSS dropdown menu using incorrect style

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on creating a top navigation menu that also features dropdown content. At the moment, the overall style I am using for the Menu is being applied to the content in the dropdown menu even though I have created a separate style for this. I believe there is conflict in how the two classes I have assigned for the dropdown content is interacting, but the ways I have tried so far have not been successful.

```css
/*Standard text formatting*/

body {
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
}
/*Main Navigation for website*/

ul.MainNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li.MainNavItem {
  float: left;
}
li.MainNavItem.right {
  float: right;
}
/*Causing problems with items in dropdown; color is applied everywhere*/

li.MainNavItem a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li.MainNavItem a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
li.MainNavItem a:hover:not(.active),
.DropDown:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
/*Makes Main Navigation responsive*/

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul.MainNav li.MainNavItem.right,
  ul.MainNav li.MainNavItem {
    float: none;
  }
}
/*Dropdown for Main Navigation*/

li.MainNavItem.DropDown {
  display: inline-block;
}
/*Color style that should be used*/

.DropDown-Content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.DropDown-Content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.DropDown-Content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
.DropDown:hover .DropDown-Content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="MainNav">
    <li class="MainNavItem"><a class="active" href="Index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="MainNavItem DropDown"><a href="News.html">News</a>
      <div class="DropDown-Content">
        <a href="#CurrentProjects">Current Projects</a>
        <a href="#Events">Events</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="MainNavItem"><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li class="MainNavItem right"><a href="About.html">About</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

I am also aware that this does not display properly when the screen size shrinks for mobile, but I will continue working on that separately. For now, I am focusing on getting the style to work before attempting to fix the responsiveness of the menu.

Comment: in your style sheet you have this notation: `element.classname` ( eg `li.MainNavItem {  ... }`) ... in your html you have this notation: `<element class = 'classname'>` .... ... so thus your stylesheet notation is unnnecessary ... you don't need the `element.classname` ... you just need `.classname` ...

Comment: also a good idea to include a link to a  [selector reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: also you will need commas where you have multiple selectors in your style sheet, such as `.DropDown:hover .DropDown-Content ` ----> change it to `.DropDown:hover , .DropDown-Content ` ... there may be more ...

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd I will work on cleaning up the code to remove the unnecessary notation, and review selector reference. As for the item at the bottom of my stylesheet, adding a comma breaks the dropdown menu by preventing it from hiding (i.e. it stays visible regardless of where the cursor is).

Comment: aha ... sorry ... I thought that was two separate selectors (`.DropDown:hover` and `.DropDown-Content`) ...  I see now ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dropdown a tag is inheriting styles from your `li.MainNavItem a`. Changing `li.MainNavItem a` to `li.MainNavItem > a` will limit the style to direct children and prevent it from applying to the dropdown.

Comment: This is exactly it. Thank you for assisting me; I've been banging my head against the wall on this for about an hour. I'll be reviewing inheritance again to hopefully prevent this from happening again in the future.